# How can I create a class derived from a reflected interface

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to call a method in a reflected class that takes an interface also defined in the reflected library

My library is a .NET461 library

```
public interface InterfaceA{
  ...
}
...
public class ClassA {
  public void MethodA( InterfaceA interface )
  {
    ...
  }  
}
```

My executable is a .NET48 executable

(removed validation and some code for brevity)

```
// get the library
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom( "...myAssembly.dll" );

// instantiate ClassA
var instance = asm.CreateInstance( "ClassA" )

// look for that class type so we can get the method "MethodA"
var class = asm.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault( t => t.Name == "ClassA" ); 

// look for the Method
var method = class.GetMethod( "MethodA");

// look for the interface
var interface = asm.GetExportedTypes().FirstOrDefault( t => t.Name == "Interface" ); 

// how can I call the method here
method.Invoke( instance, new []{ ....} );
```

I know everything about the interface, I can create an exact class that has the same methods and properties ...

But how can I create the same class in my code, so I can pass it as an argument to the reflected class?

**Edit**:
The Library has a public class, `ClassA`, and a public interface `InterfaceA`
The class `ClassA` has a method `MethodA` that takes `InterfaceA`

The library does not have a derived class I can instantiate.

I would like to know how to create a class that is derived from `InterfaceA` so I can pass it to `MethodA`

Comment: You can't without dynamic code generation, and if the class is private then it won't work anyway. Side point: You can cache `asm.GetType("ClassA")` rather than retrieving it again and again

Comment: The wording of the question creates confusion. Do you mean that you want to create a class using reflection? That's complicated. Do you mean that you want to create *an instance of a class* using reflection? That's easy.

Comment: Sorry about that, the method takes a interface as one of the argument. It does not give a class as one of the models.
So, I would like to create a class that uses the reflected Interface.
I will edit my post
I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: I know you have a good reason for wanting to do this; would you be willing to say what it is? It feels a little XY but if you could provide the context I think it could help.

Comment: That said, all your problems go away if you have an abstract `myInterfaces.dll` that exposes _just_ your interfaces and no implementations. Then, all interested parties (`Program`, `myAssembly.dll`) know what and where it is, and therefore can reference `InterfaceA` without reflection. For example, using this scheme, I've been able to say _Put `yourPlugin.dll` with your `ClassA` implementation into folder X. At runtime we'll come find all the `userPlugIn.dlls` in that folder, load them by reflection, and add them to the **PlugIns** menu._